# Objective-C handling integer values

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsinteger

I am getting confused with how to handle Integers in Objective C.

If I define the following:

```
NSInteger i = 6;
NSLog(@"%d", i);
```

I expect it to print 6 to the console.

however I have an NSInteger within an object which is obviously reference by a pointer so I get very difference results.

For example:

```
@interface Section : NSObject {
NSInteger Id;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger Id;
```

Please assume this has been synthesized in the implementation.

I create the object set its value and access it again as follows:

```
Section *section = [[Section alloc] init];
section.Id = 6;

NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[sections addobject:section];

Section *sectionB = [setions objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%d",  sectionB.Id);
```

This has the strange effect of printing the memory address ie a number like 5447889. Why can I not just get the value?

I have tried using:

```
NSInteger sid = [[section Id]integerValue];
```

But I then get the warning **Invalid receiver type 'NSInteger'** and sometime get an error **Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.**

I would really like to know how to handle Integers, or any values for that matter properly.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found the answer to my own question. Setting the value of an NSInteger to a value of say 6 is fine. The problem I have is I am setting it to the value returned from a Json string using the following:

```
NSInteger i = [jsonResult objectForKey:@"Id"];
```

which should be:

```
NSInteger i = [[jsonResult objectForKey:@"Id"] integerValue];
```

I have not tested this but makes sense based on what DarkDust said about integerValue taking an object and not an Integer.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accessing uninitialized memory; 5447889 doesn't look like a pointer value—pointers are usually word-aligned, and 5447889 isn't word aligned.

Maybe you could cut and paste your actual code. This has typos such as `addobject` instead of `addObject` and `setions` instead of `sections`.

Does it work if you keep things simple and do `NSLog(@"%d", section.Id)` to skip messing with the array?

Comment: I am unable to post the full code at this time because im away from my mac. I don't know of it helps but im my production code the value of section.Id is being set from data parsed from json. Could it be a casting issue? Regarding the number I posted 5447889, this was just some random example numbers.

Comment: You should confirm the value that you're *setting* `Id` to.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the strange values, see Dominic Cooney's answer.

Regarding the EXC_BAD_ACCESS: `[[section Id]integerValue];` doesn't work because it then tries to interpret the NSInteger as an object and tries to send the message `integerValue` to it, which can't work. It's an integral number, not an object.